# Не передает url в laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mvc

Подскажите пожалуйста, в базе есть таблица pages, есть модель Page. В этой таблице есть поле url, этот url я передаю из роута в контроллер, с контроллера во view. Но почему то ошибка 404, если передавать id то все ок. Вот роут:

```
 Route::get('/page/{url}', 'PageController@page')->where('url', '[a-z]');
```

Контроллер:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Category;
use App\Page;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PageController extends Controller
{

    protected $catalog;
    protected $page;


    public function __construct()
    {
       // Коллекция всех категорий
      $this->category = Category::all();
      // Коллекция всех страниц
      $this->page = Page::all();
    }

    public function page($url) {
        $page_show = $this->page->find($url);
        $catalog = $this->category;
        $page = $this->page;
        $title = $page_show->title;
        echo $title;

        return view('page', ['catalog' => $catalog, 'page_show' => $page_show, 'page' => $page, 'title' => $title]);
    }
}
```

Укажите на ошибку, заранее спасибо!

Comment: У Вас не правильно сделано условие `where('url', '[a-z]')`, проверяется только одна буква, должно быть так `where('url', '[a-z]+')`

Comment: Код контроллера ужасен, но @ЕвгенийНиколаев указал на проблему

Comment: В чем ужастность заключается?

Comment: Действительно тут ошибся, но всеравно что то не так, нужно получить title отдельной страницы, но вместо этого ошибка Trying to get property 'title' of non-object

Comment: @ilyaaa521 что у вас за метод find? в коллекциях нету такого метода

Comment: и вообще для чего вам получать все страницы? если вам нужна одна конкретная, так и делайте запрос на конкретную страницу.

Comment: Что-бы вывести все страницы в главном меню в шапке, только для этого, предложите вариант по лучше?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получать модель по url - нужно сначала в ней прописать метод:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'url';
}
```

Теперь везде можно будет только достать по `url`. По `id` - не сработает. Тут осторожно!

Дальше в роуте - `[a-z]+` - таким образом `url` будет только буквенной.

```
 Route::get('/page/{url}', 'PageController@page')->where('url', '[a-z]+');
```

А теперь контроллер:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Category;
use App\Page;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PageController extends Controller
{

    protected $catalog;
    protected $page;

    public function __construct()
    {
       // Коллекция всех категорий
      $this->category = Category::all();
      // Коллекция всех страниц
      $this->page = Page::all();
    }

    public function page(Page $singlePage) {
        $page_show = $singlePage;
        $catalog = $this->category;
        $page = $this->page;
        $title = $page_show->title;
        echo $title;

        return view('page', ['catalog' => $catalog, 'page_show' => $page_show, 'page' => $page, 'title' => $title]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но по прежнему не выводится title

Comment: @ilyaaa521 сделайте `dd($page_show)` перед `returt...` и покажите сюда

Comment: App\Page {#265 ▼
  #table: "pages"
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
}